# How to fix missing vertices

Tags: vertices

I'm trying to follow a tutorial in youtube. But I'm facing some problem with the vertices. See image1, noticed that the vertices are still some how present but right after I 'apply' the subdivision modifier, a lot of the vertices were gone (see image2).

- What could be the cause of this?
- How can I fix this?
- How can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

Comment: they are not gone, they are just hidden by the other object, you can activate the Snap option, choose Snap To Face, and move the faces so that they stick to the other object surface

Comment: Hi @moonboots, apologies but i did not quite understand how to do what you mean. Before I have ended up on this issue I already turn "SNAP+FACE+Project Individual Elements" on, then I apply the subdivision.

Comment: Also enable the Project Individual Elements option so that each vertex will snap to the surface of the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vertices are hidden under the other torus surface.

In the *Snap* panel, choose the *Face* option and also enable *Project Individual Elements*. You don't have to click on the *Snap* tool itself (magnet icon), you can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when you'll want to snap.

[image]

Then switch your object to *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to see your mesh by transparency, select the vertices you want to move, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap them to the surface of the other object:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @moonboots.
I can now see the vertices :)